# Correlation ID in Header Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using kafka conluent c# client for kafka and want to implement Req-Resp pattern.
I set Reply-to and Correlation ID header (`https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/enums/kafka-headers.enum.ts`) CORRELATION_ID/REPLY_TOPIC in the request.

I receive these headers on "server" side and reply into REPLY_TOPIC header's value topic.
I probably should set CORRELATION_ID on response header.

So questions are:

1. Is there any magic inside kafka that looks for CORRELATION_ID on message's header and pushes to consumers with appropriate settings?
2. MB somebody knows and points me how spring-kafka implement req-resp pattern?

Comment: Hey @Yuriy Vikulov were you able to successfully implement this system? / Would you be able to share your method?

Comment: I am attempting the same thing, need some request response in kafka for UI interaction, in an otherwise iot based system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Kafka to do that; spring-kafka uses its own custom headers for these purposes. See `KafkaHeaders`.

If you are using Spring on the server side (`@KafkaListener`) you need to set those headers. The framework then echoes the correlation id into the reply and uses the topic for the destination.

If you are writing your own server code, you need to do the same.

```java
    /**
     * The prefix for Kafka headers.
     */
    public static final String PREFIX = "kafka_";

...

    /**
     * The header containing information to correlate requests/replies.
     * Type: byte[].
     * @since 2.1.3
     */
    public static final String CORRELATION_ID = PREFIX + "correlationId";

    /**
     * The header containing the default reply topic.
     * Type: byte[].
     * @since 2.1.3
     */
    public static final String REPLY_TOPIC = PREFIX + "replyTopic";
```